# Combine two Mod Rewrite Rules

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

**Current Status:**
Firstly, I would like to point out that this question is very much related to a question which I posted two days ago.  I have since tried to tackle the problem I was facing a different way and have encountered different problems.  I hope this does not constitute any sort of "double-post"?

I have created two mod rewrite rules which seem to work in isolation to create the desired effect.  These are shown below:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?([A-Za-z0-9.-]+)_([A-Za-z0-9.-]*) $1?$2=$3&%1 [L]
```

The above rule takes a URL like this:

```
www.site.com/param1/thing/sortorder_5/getparam2_6/
```

and converts it into this:

```
www.site.com/param1/thing/?sortorder=5&getparam2_6/
```

The second rule is as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?((?:cmd)[^/]*)/((?!(?:cmd)[.+]*)(.+)) $1?$2=$3&%1 [L]
```

This takes a URL like this:

```
http://www.site.com/cmd/param1/thing/cmd2/param2/
```

and converts it into this:

```
http://www.site.com?cmd=param1/thing&cmd2=param/
```

**Desired Outcome:**

I would like to merge these two rewrite rules so that I may be able to do the following:

```
http://www.site.com/cmd/param1/cmd2/param2/sortorder_5
```

converts to:

```
http://www.site.com?cmd=param1&cmd2=param2&sortorder=5
```

Anybody who tells me how to begin doing so would be most kind.  I have experimented with LOTS of mod rewrite code for days, with no luck.  My regex/mod rewrite knowledge really isn't up to scratch, so my apologies for that!  The whole mod rewrite code is pasted below.  Thank you.

```
RewriteEngine On

# This block works fine in isolation
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?([A-Za-z0-9.-]+)_([A-Za-z0-9.-]*) $1?$2=$3&%1 [L]

# This block also works fine in isolation
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?((?:cmd)[^/]*)/((?!(?:cmd)[.+]*)(.+)) $1?$2=$3&%1 [L]

# This block should append the query string to index.php (front controller)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?%1 [L]
```

Comment: If you have control over `index.php` I suggest just doing something like `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?query=$1 [L,QSA]` and parsing the query in the script. That way, apart from making parsing of the request easier, you are not depending on mod_rewrite rules (can easily be used with other servers).

Comment: Btw, why are you using `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)` like that? I suggest just using `QSA` flag on your rewrite rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tested and works:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(cmd[^/]*)/([^/]+)/?(.*)$ $3?$1=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z\d.-]+)_([a-z\d.-]+)/?(.*)$ $3?$1=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

See [mod_rewrite docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) about the flags.

Example request:

```
http://localhost:8080/test/cmd1/foo/cmd2/bar/foo_bar/cmd42/everything
```

Ends up at:

```
http://localhost:8080/test/index.pl?cmd42=everything&foo=bar&cmd2=bar&cmd1=foo
```

With the `.htaccess` located at `/test/`, and `index.pl` printing its query string:

```
cmd42=everything&foo=bar&cmd2=bar&cmd1=foo
```

This request has the redirect log:

```
[rid#2f0b590/initial] (2) [perdir /root_http/test/] rewrite 'cmd1/foo/cmd2/bar/foo_bar/cmd42/everything' -> 'cmd2/bar/foo_bar/cmd42/everything?cmd1=foo'
[rid#2f0b590/initial] (2) [perdir /root_http/test/] strip document_root prefix: /root_http/test/cmd2/bar/foo_bar/cmd42/everything -> /test/cmd2/bar/foo_bar/cmd42/everything
[rid#2f0b590/initial] (1) [perdir /root_http/test/] internal redirect with /test/cmd2/bar/foo_bar/cmd42/everything [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[rid#10dec40/initial/redir#1] (2) [perdir /root_http/test/] rewrite 'cmd2/bar/foo_bar/cmd42/everything' -> 'foo_bar/cmd42/everything?cmd2=bar'
[rid#10dec40/initial/redir#1] (2) [perdir /root_http/test/] strip document_root prefix: /root_http/test/foo_bar/cmd42/everything -> /test/foo_bar/cmd42/everything
[rid#10dec40/initial/redir#1] (1) [perdir /root_http/test/] internal redirect with /test/foo_bar/cmd42/everything [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[rid#2e16d90/initial/redir#2] (2) [perdir /root_http/test/] rewrite 'foo_bar/cmd42/everything' -> 'cmd42/everything?foo=bar'
[rid#2e16d90/initial/redir#2] (2) [perdir /root_http/test/] strip document_root prefix: /root_http/test/cmd42/everything -> /test/cmd42/everything
[rid#2e16d90/initial/redir#2] (1) [perdir /root_http/test/] internal redirect with /test/cmd42/everything [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[rid#2f0d558/initial/redir#3] (2) [perdir /root_http/test/] rewrite 'cmd42/everything' -> '?cmd42=everything'
[rid#2f0d558/initial/redir#3] (2) [perdir /root_http/test/] strip document_root prefix: /root_http/test/ -> /test/
[rid#2f0d558/initial/redir#3] (1) [perdir /root_http/test/] internal redirect with /test/ [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[rid#2f0eac8/initial/redir#4] (1) [perdir /root_http/test/] pass through /root_http/test/
[rid#10c98b0/subreq] (1) [perdir /root_http/test/] pass through /root_http/test/index.html
[rid#10c98b0/subreq] (1) [perdir /root_http/test/] pass through /root_http/test/index.shtml
[rid#10c98b0/subreq] (1) [perdir /root_http/test/] pass through /root_http/test/index.cgi
[rid#10c98b0/subreq] (1) [perdir /root_http/test/] pass through /root_http/test/index.fcgi
[rid#10c98b0/subreq] (1) [perdir /root_http/test/] pass through /root_http/test/index.pl
```

This log can be seen by adding this in your server config:

```
RewriteLog "logs/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 2
```

Comment: No luck with the answer, unfortunately, but thank you very much for the reply.  I did like your suggestion of simply appending the whole URL to the index.php and parsing it that way; much more straightforward.

I'm curious, though, how this may allow it to be used on more servers?  Surely mod rewrite would have to be enabled in the server configuration for even that single RewriteRule to take effect?

Comment: Other servers could have alternative ways to pass such data to your script. Which you can set up in config or some other kind rewrite rules.

Comment: that works well!  I'm afraid I have another question - I forgot to include a very important point in my description: the cmd values can be over several directories.  Therefore cmd/valuepart1/valuepart2/ would be one command in a URL that may look like this: `www.site.com/cmd/valpart1/valpart2/cmd2/anotherval/regulargetparam_here`.  I tried using negative lookaheads in a modified version of your regex with no luck.  Do you have any chance how this would be achieved?

If you can't find the time to reply, of course, I'll still mark the above as the answer! You've been a great help. Thanks!

Comment: What should the resulting query string of `cmd/valpart1/valpart2` be? And where should the values end? What about `cmd/val_part1/val_part2`?

Comment: @Qtax.Sorry, I could only fit so much more in the comment.  It should parse as `cmd=valpart1/valpart2&cmd2=anotherval&regulargetparam=here`.  Hope that clears it up.

Comment: So what about `cmd/val_part1/val_part2`? How should we know when `cmd` parameters end and when it's a `foo_bar`? If no `_` are allowed as `cmd` parameters you could change the first rule to: `RewriteRule ^(cmd[^/]*)/([^/]+(?:/(?!cmd)[^/_]+)*)/?(.*)$ $3?$1=$2 [QSA,NC,L]`

Comment: Yes, cmd parameters cannot contain underscores; sorry if I neglected to mention that.

I actually ended up parsing the URL in PHP... much easier!  Nonetheless, thanks for all your help.